# How to implement exposure image filter using fabricjs basefilter?

Tags: fabricjs

I would like to know how can we implement exposure filter in fabric js.After some R&D I came to know that we can implement a custom filter in fabricjs using basefilter but I am not aware of the calculation to be used to implement exposure filter for an image.Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Exposure filter is generally a gamma filter.

given a gamma value you want to correct, the alghoritm generally look like this:

```
applyTo() {
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i += 4) {
        data[i] = Math.pow(data[i] / 255, adjustment) * 255;
        data[i + 1] = Math.pow(data[i + 1] / 255, adjustment) * 255;
        data[i + 2] = Math.pow(data[i + 2] / 255, adjustment) * 255;
    }
}
```

where data is the imageData.data of your image.

Where adjustment is 1/gamma.
So for gamma of 1.5 you adjustment will look like 1/1.5

Comment: Thanks @AndreaBogazzi.I have tried this logic .It seems to work but not properly.For negative values of adjustment,its just making the image white while for positive values its darkening the image.Can you suggest me the range values that I should use for achieving desired results?

Comment: Thanks @AndreaBogazzi.I have used inverted adjustment values(just like you suggested) for increasing exposure and normal values for decreasing exposure.Seems to work fine.Can you help me with this as well. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40840063/top-left-coordinates-not-updated-on-rotating-image-using-fabricjs)

Comment: @Ashish Would have been great if you actually posted your code!