# Top-Left coordinates not updated on rotating image using fabricjs

Tags: fabricjs

When I rotate an image in fabricjs, the top-left corner's coordinates are not updated after rotated. Instead, the top-left corner of the image still refers to the old point. I believe that it should recalculate the top-left corner based on the image's new position. Is there a way to achieve this? Any help is appreciated!

Below is the code for image rotation:

```
    function rotate(){    
        activeCanvas.forEachObject(function(obj){
            if(obj instanceof fabric.Image){
                curAngle = obj.getAngle();
                obj.setAngle(curAngle-90);            
            }
        });
        activeCanvas.renderAll();
    }
```

Now, after the rotation, I want top-left coordinates of the new rotated image but it still returns top and left from the old image state.

For example, let say the image's top-left corner was originally at (100,200) and the image's dimensions are 500x600. Now, if I rotate the image in 90 degrees, the new dimensions are 600x500 and the top-left corner changes as well, as the image is rotated related to its center. But the fabricjs image still refers to the old top-left corner. Is there any method just like `setCoords()` to get the new upper left corner point as its top left?

Comment: we are missing your code

Comment: @jansuz thanks for the reply.Please refer to edited question description for better understanding of requirement.

Comment: use the getBoundingRect()

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the snippet below, if you only rotate your object, only the bounding box will be updated, you have to move your object to have the position of your object updated.

```js
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 120,
  top: 30,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  fill: 'green',
  angle: 20
});
canvas.on("object:rotating", function() {
  var ao = canvas.getActiveObject();
  if(ao){
    console.log('top and left are the same after rotation');
    console.log('top:' + ao.top);
    console.log('left:' + ao.left);
    
    console.log('but not the bounding box');
    var bound = ao.getBoundingRect();
    console.log('bounding box - top:' + bound.top);
    console.log('bounding box - left:' + bound.left);

  }
})
canvas.add(rect);
canvas.renderAll();
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://seikichi.github.io/tmp/PDFJS.0.8.715/pdf.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
canvas.on('object:rotating', function(options) {
  options.target.setCoords();
  var left = options.target.oCoords.tl.x,
      top = options.target.oCoords.tl.y;
  console.log(left, top);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @janusz.But actually I dont want the new top left coordinates,I want the fabricjs image's top and left to point to current top left point rather than always pointing to same corner point.Also,if i use these new coordinates and set them to image's top and left,then the image gets translated to that point.

Comment: @jansuz refer to edited question description for better understanding of requirement.

Comment: I think I know now what you are looking for. As far as I know there is no such function in FabricJS but I think you should check out the `oCoords` object of any fabric object. It contains all corners coordinates (`tl` - top left corner, `br`- bottom right corner etc). The coordinates you are looking for will be the coordinates of one of the four corners (tl, tr, br, bl) depending on the object's rotation, ie. if the angle is between 0 and 90 you take the value of `tl`, between 90 and 180 you take `bl` and so forths. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I was able to use setCoords method and get the new left top corner points but what  I wanted was to know whether the image can itself refer to its new top left coordinates .Anyways ,I used setCoords() to get the desired implementation .Thanks for your help.