# prevent fabric from updating top/left after rotation

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Is it possible to keep fabric from updating an object's top/left after rotation? I have positioning code that depends on the objects top/left to be at the original coordinates. Would it be possible to have the object show as rotated and be selectable, but its movement based on an imaginary object at the position before rotation?

Comment: Take a look at this, http://stackoverflow.com/a/40844323/3389046.  The top and left will remain the same after rotation.  Hope it helps.  Thanks for the help, @bhargav-rao.